# How do you set the property of a model instance while using generic view to create it?

Tags: django

Let's say trying to use django.views.generic.create_update.create_object to allow the user to a blog entry instance.  On the Entry model, there is a required field for the user, that I don't want to show up as an editable field on the blog entry form.  So, I would include it into the EntryForm.Meta.exclude tuple.

Where should I set the value for the user property on the resulting model instance?  Would I have to stop using the create_object generic view and write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this with generic views, they don't have much in the way of post-processing data. Thankfully, it isn't hard to write your own view to do the same thing.

(Adapted from http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter07/)

```
from yourmodel.forms import EntryForm

def create_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry = form.save(commit = false)
            entry.author = request.user.username
            entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_entry/thanks/')
    else:
        form = EntryForm()
    return render_to_response('/path/to/template.html', {'form' : form, ...}, ...)
```

Of course you'll have to use your own names and such, but that's the logic. Basically you're checking if a form has been submitted, and if so get the Entry, add in a username, and save it as usual. As far as differences from the generic create_object view are concerned, instead of specifying things such as the post_redirect_url in the view call, you give them directly. Check the docs of render_to_response and HttpResponseRedirect for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve this problem, and didn't want to cheat.  It wasn't hard.  Check the below.

Please note that it's only this convoluted because I chose to adhere to my view of the MVC separation on this.  The user population is view-specific (since we have no special initial user in Edit).  The handling is model-specific.

It wouldn't be hard to extract a form mixin that expects a new "passthrough" parameter and automatically merges an exclude with a forwarding of initial data.  This also adds the security of knowing nobody can modify those fields' data in the View.

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('user')
        model = models.Test

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(CharmForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.initial['user']

        if commit:
            obj.save()

class TestView(CreateView):
    model = models.Test
    form_class = TestForm
    def get_initial(self,**kwargs):
        initial = super(CreateView,self).get_initial()

        c = RequestContext(self.request)

        initial = initial.copy()
        initial['user'] = c['user']
        return initial
```

Also, not totally sure if you were trying to use the new Class-Based views.  I'm actually answering this question for anyone with this problem (I had to hack code to find the answer because nobody else seems to have done it).

Answer (score 0):

There is one little problem with sykora's solution: if the form is invalid you will get an error because form won't be set (outside of the scope of the if statement).

Here's a slightly better version:

```
from yourmodel.forms import EntryForm

def create_entry(request):
    form = EntryForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry = form.save(commit = false)
            entry.author = request.user.username
            entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_entry/thanks/')
    return render_to_response('/path/to/template.html', {'form' : form, ...}, ...)
```